# Need to block Access to SharePoint List through External Clients such as Microsoft Access or Excel

Tags: sharepoint-server

Sensitive data kept in SharePoint list. And only data can be access through CSOM or Server Object Model in SharePoint , data should not be exposed to Microsoft Access or Excel, Any idea how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of SharePoint, but since you mention Server Object Model it's not online, so I'm going to assume your version is 2013 or greater.

There really isn't a way to configure this type of access in SharePoint. Access control is entirely based on the current user and the securable object that they are trying to access, not the API they are using to access it.

The only way I can thing of to do it is with a perimeter firewall between your users and the SharePoint enclave. It still wouldn't be easy, and you'd probably need to do a lot of sniffing to see how those applications access SharePoint. For instance, to block REST, you could try blocking anything with */_api/*. You'd need a different rule to block the ASMX web services. And maybe Webdav? But I'm oversimplifying still, because you probably can't block all REST or some of the OOB SharePoint browser interface would stop working? And certainly any client side customization using JSOM or REST would break.

It's a pretty slippery slope to even consider this though, because by the time you're done, you may find that your blocking things you didn't want to block. For instance, blocking ASMX also means SharePoint designer won't work. And I don't know what protocol explorer view uses. etc.

BTW, you could also achieve the same thing by writing an HTTP module and deploying it to you SharePoint WFEs. You could then debug it, and connect with one of the client apps you want to block to see how you can identify it, and then redirect to the access denied page for that app. This gives you a bit more control because if you can figure out a way to identify an app that you don't want to block (again, maybe designer), then you could specifically let that through.

Just keep in mind that you would now be intercepting every call to SharePoint, so if your solution crashes, SharePoint is down too. Also, intercepting every call, you have to be very mindful of performance. The average SharePoint page load is actually about 45 HTTP requests, so to help performance you might need to do things like identify static images (i.e. _layouts/images) and static JavaScript/CSS and ignore those requests.

This is not for the faint of heart or an endeavor to be taken lightly, nor is it a question that can be reasonably answered in detail on an internet forum.